# Unity C# how to share data across classes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to develop a unity game whereby the user moves objects around accoding to data entered into a texbox. But I am unable to make the data from a textbox apply to an object that I want to move.
Here is C# script for the textbox:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ButtonText : MonoBehaviour
{

private bool defineModel = false;
    string beta = "";
    public float number ;
    bool res ;

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (!defineModel) {
                if (GUI.Button (new Rect (0, 0, 150, 20), "Define a shift"))
                                defineModel = true;
              } else {  
                        beta = GUI.TextField (new Rect (250, 157, 250, 25), beta, 40);
                         res = float.TryParse(beta, out number); 
                         if (res == false) { print("String is not a number");  }
                         else { number = float.Parse(beta);  }

                    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (300, 250, 100, 30), "OK")) {
                            if(!res) return;
                else { Debug.Log (" number = "  + number);
                                defineModel = false;
                                return; }

                        }
                }

    }
```

and here is script to create a sphere to be moved during the game

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CloneSphere : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject sphere;
    void Start() 
    {
        GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere); // Make a new sphere
        sphere.name = "Sphere"; // give it a name
        sphere.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0); // position the sphere
        }
    float number;

    void Update () {
    sphere = GameObject.Find("Sphere");
        float location = GetComponent<ButtonText>().number ;
        sphere.transform.Translate(0, location ,0, Space.World); 
    }
}
```

The last two lines of the latter script generate an error (i.e., if I comment these two lines out, there is no error):
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
CloneSphere.Update () (at Assets/CloneSphere.cs:20)

What is wrong here? How can I make this number "location" apply to the vertical shift of the sphere?

Comment: Unity tag in SO isn't intended for Unity3d game engine. Please use unity3d tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your two scripts are not attached to the same object: when `ScriptA` calls `GetComponent<ScriptB>()`, it's assumed they're attached to the same object, otherwise it can never work. A solution that works across the whole loaded scene (active objects only) is `FindObjectOfType<ScriptB>()`.

Though `FindObjectOfType<T>()` isn't a very fast function. It's more suited to code toy/testing code, and code that really can't work in any other way. (In particular, singletons are faster, which is a class that only has one instance, and a static accessor that references that instance.)

Comment: Thank you ; that helped. You ar right that I had set the textbox and shpere as a different game objects. Just now I deleted the sphere and then added the CloneShpere script to the ButtonText object (using the "Add Component" button). The sphere now moves.

Comment: Glad to help. BTW, you can click the "check" icon next to the answer, to accept an answer as the correct one.

Comment: Is attaching the same textbox script to every object (eg. sphere) the only solution? My aim is for one click of the textbox "OK" to define a "data set" of locations, one location for each of many objects (eg. potentially thousands). Each particular object only needs to access its particular location in order to reposition. So it seems inefficient to me to have the entire textbox object attached to every sphere!

Comment: Oh, no. Like I said, you can use FindObjectOfType instead of GetComponent. This is still inefficient, so another option is to make the number static (though I suggest making it local-write, world-read): `public static float yInput { get; private set; }`, then the circles can access it by checking `ButtonText.yInput`.

Comment: But these static variables can get sloppy, so if you need to access more than one piece of data, it's good to make that class into a singleton: so `ButtonText.Instance` will be a static variable that refers to the one and only `ButtonText`. In `Awake`, `ButtonText` should set the value (`Instance = this;`). In that case, the spheres would query the value as `ButtonText.Instance.yInput`.

Comment: Thanks again. OK it sounds like I want ButtonText class to be a singleton. I that case I suppose I do not attach (using "Add Component") that class to every sphere, right? Suppose I have 100 spheres named sphere001, sphere002, etc. and I want "sphere001" to access just the first number within that ButtonText singleton, sphere050 to access just the fiftieth, etc? Can you help me out here ; what would my "sphere.transform.Translate" command look like? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted just one text input. If you want one text input per sphere, it would probably be fine to attach them to the spheres. Singletons are for when you really only need one instance of some code.

Comment: i want one textbox input to be used subsequently to define an array of positions, eg, parameters of a math function that are then used to model separate positions for each sphere. Think of a regression model that defines positions for a bunch of poiints using just with a few parameters plus a random componeht, .

Comment: Gotcha. Then a singleton would work fine, but either the spheres would need to have separate scripts controlling each one, or the spheres could have variables (set in the inspector) that determine which field they use. For example, you could have an enum that defined tags for each field (`enum Tag { Height, Width };`) in the label class, and in that class would need to associate values with each tag. Then the spheres would know which tag they need, and get it by calling `ButtonText.Instance.GetValue(Tag.Height)`, for example. ButtonText will store the values in a `Dictionary<Tag, float>`.